# Proving that a sentence is true in the language of predicate logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

I have recently completed self-studying from a 'transition' type textbook concerning proofs in mathematics and have decided to continue with a philosophical logic book'**the logic manual**' by **Halbach**.I tried to input this question in philosophy.stackexchange but for some reason,the math formatting does not work...so i hope i can post this here!

I am having trouble with understanding the following problem and would appreciate some help !

> Consider the $L_2-structure$ $A$ with
>
> - Domain of discourse the set of all European cities.
> - $|Q^1|_A=\{Florence,Stockholm,Barcelona \}$
> - $|R^2|_A=\{<d,e> : \text{d is smaller than e}\}$
> - $|a|_A=Florence$
> - $|b|_A=London$
>
> Prove : $|\forall x \exists y (R^2xy   \lor R^2yx)|_A=T$

**Informal Attempt:**

Since the formula between $|\dots|$ does not contain any free variables,it is classified as a sentence in $L_2$.

By definition of truth in an $L_2-structure$,$|\forall x \exists y (R^2xy   \lor R^2yx)|_A=T$ **iff** $|\forall x \exists y (R^2xy   \lor R^2yx)|_A ^\alpha=T$ for all variable assignments $\alpha$ over $A$.

Therefore:

1. Let $\alpha$ be a variable assignment over $A$.The objective is to prove that $|\forall x \exists y (R^2xy   \lor R^2yx)|_A ^\alpha =T$.
2. By successively applying the satisfaction definitions,I ended up with the following proof diagram:

   Let $\alpha$ be any variable assignment over $A$.
   $\quad$ Let $\beta$ be any variable assignment over $A$ differeing from $\alpha$ at most in $x$.
   $\quad \quad$ Let $\gamma$ be the variable assignment found that differs from $\beta$ in $y$ at most.
   $\quad \quad \quad$ Prove $|R^2xy \lor R^2yx|_A ^\gamma = T$
3. Given the way $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$ are related i thought we
   could eliminate $\beta$ and directly write:

   Let $\alpha$ be any variable assignment over $A$.
   $\quad \quad$
   Let $\gamma$ be the variable assignment found that differs from
   $\alpha$ in $y$ and $x$ at most.
   $\quad \quad \quad$ Prove $|R^2xy|_A ^\gamma=T$ or $|R^2yx|_A ^\gamma = T$

In the light of the above, the objective is to find a variable assignment $\gamma$ such that it differs from $\alpha$ at most in x and y such that $|R^2xy|_A ^\gamma=T$ or $|R^2yx|_A ^\gamma = T$.

Therefore, I thought I should try to 'reverse-engineer' $\gamma$ as follows:

1. By satisfaction :  $|R^2xy|_A ^\gamma=T$  **iff**  $<|x|_A ^\gamma,|y|_A ^\gamma> \in |R^2|_A ^\gamma$.
   Then defining $\gamma$ such that it assigns $|x|_A ^\gamma=NotLondon$ and $|y|_A ^\gamma=London$,yields $<|x|_A ^\gamma,|y|_A ^\gamma> \in |R^2|_A ^\gamma$ as required since any european city is smaller than London.
2. By satisfaction :  $|R^2yx|_A ^\gamma=T$  **iff**  $<|y|_A ^\gamma,|x|_A ^\gamma> \in |R^2|_A ^\gamma$.
   Then defining $\gamma$ such that it assigns $|x|_A ^\gamma=London$ and $|y|_A ^\gamma=NotLondon$,yields $<|y|_A ^\gamma,|x|_A ^\gamma> \in |R^2|_A ^\gamma$ as required since any european city is smaller than London.

...now if this is correct so far,how do i relate $\gamma$ such that it differs from $\alpha$ at most in x and y?? Since $\alpha$ is arbitrary,presumably we can choose it to be whatever we need it to be??

The proof in the book begins by making a distinction between 2 cases at the outset:

$|x|_A ^\alpha=NotLondon$ and $|x|_A ^\alpha=London$ and goes on from there.

Although i understnad how it proceeds,as usual with textbooks there is no explanation as to why.

Help someone! I have tried my best to format this stuff!
Thanks

Comment: IMO, the proof in the book assumes that London is the bigegr city in Europe: what about Istanbul ?

Comment: I guess it depends on how one defines size/Europe :-)

Comment: Having said that, same approach of your other post : either *(i)* $\alpha$ maps $x$ to a city different from London, in which case we can assing London to $y$ in order to satisfy $R^2xy$ disjunct, or *(ii)* it maps $x$ to London, in which case it is enough to map $y$ to the first city in the universe different from London in order to satisfy $R^2yx$.

Comment: Samq question: Can one rigourously reverse engineer the case distinctions in the first place?